# Illustrator: Type in circular vector & background colour disappearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having problems adding text using the type path tool in illustrator within a round vector.

Every time I go to type on a path though the background colour disappears. Here's an example:

[image]

If anyone can help and it's the blue area I want to get circular text within.

I also tried saving it as an image and creating new paths, but get the anchors lined up without the background turning white...any small suggestion on how I could do this would be great.

Comment: If you press and hold the mouse on the Text tool it will reveal a Type on a Path tool. As @iuliux mentioned, odds are you'll get a detailed proper answer on GD as your question is related to design tools not programming

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what "blue area" you mean since I see no blue but i'll assume you mean the black area.

You need two paths for the text  - top arc and bottom arc. Then you'll need the paths for the artwork behind it.

For the text, create a circle where you want the baseline of the top text to fall. Then select the Type On a Path Tool from the Tool Panel:

[image: Type on a path]

Click the path and type your text. Adjust font, size, etc. as desired. Use the Selection Tool (Black Arrow) to click and drag the I-Beam on the path to move the type along the path. You may need to do this to position the text on the path properly.

Then copy that path with the text. Change the text (using the Type on a Path Tool) to whatever the bottom text should read. Again, use the Selection Tool (black arrow) to move the I-Beam and position the text properly.

Then choose Object > Type on a Path > Type on a Path Options.

[image: Options]

You'll want to tick the "Flip" box and set the alignment to "Ascender".

Now select both the top text and the bottom text with the Selection Tool and use the align buttons to align both objects on vertical and horizontal centers. You should end up with both parts fo the text. Simply place this above other artwork.

[image: pieces]

Answer (score 2):

it's because it's turning your ellipse in to a text path. that's why  the filled colour is no longer visible. what you can do is lock your design and draw another ellipse on top of your design to match the original ellipse, and use that ellipse as your text path.  And you can set up other stuff like Scott mention above.

Comment: Perhaps a little faster and simpler to just copy the shape, paste in place, then use the Type on a Path tool. It eliminates the possibility of position or shape errors.