# Illustrator: Arc with text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

I have the following (concentric) circle, that I divided into arcs using Pathfinder/Divide. Now, I want to fill the arcs with text, so that the text has the same curvature of the arc. I tried to do it using the type tool/area type tool, then Appearance/Convert to shape. But then I can only select a rectangle.
I also tried to type on a path, but it won't align to the center correctly.

This is how I want it to look like:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Type on a Path](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-type-path.html)

- Draw a circle where you want the baseline of the type to be.
- Grab the **Type on a Path Tool**
  [image]
- Click the circle with the Type on a Path Tool
- Type

You can then adjust the type in standard ways, size, alignment, etc.

To move the type along the path, use the **Selection Tool** (Black arrow) and click-drag the middle I-beam indicator on the path.

[image]

<sub>--- I changed the type alignment from left aligned to center aligned, that's why you see the type jump to the bottom of the circle in the animation above... to center it on the underlying path. ----</sub>

---

Any standard path works for Type on a Path. I merely used a circle because it fits your sample image.

In your sample image, you'll need *4 separate paths for type*. Each path can only have one type instance for Type on a Path. You can merely draw a circle and cut it into 4 separate sections, then add Type on a Path to each section individually.

---

Related

- [How do you create an arc for text without distorting in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101077/how-do-you-create-an-arc-for-text-without-distorting-in-illustrator)
- [How to get Text to follow semicircular path, read left to right and oriented counterclockwise](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29651/how-to-get-text-to-follow-semicircular-path-read-left-to-right-and-oriented-cou)
- [Illustrator: Type in circular vector & background colour disappearing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/illustrator-type-in-circular-vector-background-colour-disappearing)